# How to retrieve a list of files for specific commit

Tags: git

I need the list of files that existed in the repository as of specified commit.

I know that for the current branch, The command is:

```
git ls-files
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to checkout temporarily to that commit state and run the command you mentioned.

```
git checkout <commit_id>
git ls-files
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid modified the git directory. it seems that my question is a duplicate and the original answer solves my problem quit well